# Duplicate S3 OnCreated Events - Lambda not expiring

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

**Description of Problem**

I have an S3 bucket that I am using to store stages of a multipart process that runs as follows:

1. Get list of new objects in Database
2. Request each object from Database
3. Parse object from XML to JSON
4. Send JSON to API

I'm currently using an EventHandler function to direct the OnCreated:* events:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var eventString = JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)

    var key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    var suffix = key.substr(key.lastIndexOf('.'));

    var lambda = new aws.Lambda({
        region: 'eu-west-1'
    });

    function invokeLambda(func){
        console.log('Received event:', eventString);
        lambda.invoke({
            FunctionName: func,
            Payload: eventString,
            InvocationType: 'Event'
        }, function(error, data) {
          if (error) {
            context.done('error: '+ error);
          }
          if(data){
              context.succeed(data);
          }
        });
    }

    switch(suffix) {
    case '.ppapgo':
        console.log('invoking 2');
        invokeLambda('2');
        break;
    case '.ppap':
        console.log('invoking 3');
        invokeLambda('3');
        break;
    case '.json':
        console.log('invoking 4');
        invokeLambda('4');
        break;
    }
};
```

Each of the files in created using `S3.upload(file)` however I am getting duplicate events being created for single files.  The only differences between the two events are:

- eventTime
- responseElements.x-amz-request-id
- responseElements.x-amz-id-2
- s3.object.sequencer

I know for definite the process 2 is completing successfully and a single `.ppap` file is created and both instances of process 3 complete successfully without going near their time or memory limits.

**Other Notes:**

- The files that I seem to have problems with are at least 9KB.
- During process 2 multiple files pdf files are created.

**Example Duplicate Events:**

Event 1

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "eventVersion": "2.0",
            "eventSource": "aws:s3",
            "awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
            "eventTime": **"2017-04-11T10:22:04.663Z"**,
            "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
            "userIdentity": {
                "principalId": "AWS:SomeJunk:2"
            },
            "requestParameters": {
                "sourceIPAddress": "IPADDRESS"
            },
            "responseElements": {
                "x-amz-request-id": **"REQUESTID1"**,
                "x-amz-id-2": **"AMZID1"**
            },
            "s3": {
                "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
                "configurationId": "ConfigId",
                "bucket": {
                    "name": "MyBucket",
                    "ownerIdentity": {
                        "principalId": "PRINCIPALID"
                    },
                    "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
                },
                "object": {
                    "key": "filename.ppap",
                    "size": 10126,
                    "eTag": "eTag",
                    "sequencer": **"SEQUENCER1"**
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Event 2:

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "eventVersion": "2.0",
            "eventSource": "aws:s3",
            "awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
            "eventTime": **"2017-04-11T10:22:05.133Z"**,
            "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
            "userIdentity": {
                "principalId": "AWS:SomeJunk:2"
            },
            "requestParameters": {
                "sourceIPAddress": "IPADDRESS"
            },
            "responseElements": {
                "x-amz-request-id": **"REQUESTID2"**,
                "x-amz-id-2": **"AMZID2"**
            },
            "s3": {
                "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
                "configurationId": "ConfigId",
                "bucket": {
                    "name": "MyBucket",
                    "ownerIdentity": {
                        "principalId": "PRINCIPALID"
                    },
                    "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
                },
                "object": {
                    "key": "filename.ppap",
                    "size": 10126,
                    "eTag": "etag",
                    "sequencer": **"SEQUENCER2"**
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sequencer is different, then this is **not** a case duplicate events.  For a given object key and a given bucket, the sequencer is used to unambiguously communicate the order in which two (or more) operations occurred against that key.  (The relative sequencer values across events have no defined meaning when the events occur against different object keys or in different buckets.)

You are getting two events because you are  uploading the object twice.

The difference in the timestamps, and the id/id2 also confirms this.  There's really no other possible explanation, so you'll need to investigate why your code is unexpectedly doing this.